# Pasting formatted text from MS-Word

Tags: posts, formatting

I want to paste into Wordpress posts large amounts of text stored in MS-Word files.

When I directly copy-paste from MS-Word, the page usually breaks because of various MS-Word control characters.

So I prefer to save my text as .txt and then copy pure text and paste it in Wordpress.

However, I then lose all formatting, like bold and italics.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can take a look at the XML-RPC function and using Microsoft Live Writer. I think this will keep all your formats in tact.

Further is gives you a nice interface to work with in a desktop environment. All you have to do is enable this function in the backend, options -> write.

Download and install Microsoft Live Writer and you are ready to go.

http://en.wordpress.com/windows-live-writer/

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the paste from Word button on the toolbar. The option is under the kitchen sink view. Here is more info: http://blogsolace.com/how-to-use-the-paste-from-word-feature-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux at least, the Word-paste button loses a lot of useful formatting, such as titles or tables, and even bold and italics.

A work-around that I am using is by HTML export, and copy-pasting the HTML code into the HTML input box of Wordpress. For this, you need the HTML export to be clean enough, this is now mostly the case with OpenOffice-produced HTML.

To do this:

- Open document in OpenOffice writer
- List item
- Save as HTML
- Open HTML in notepad or other text editing tool
- Select the relevant section and copy it
- Open the post in Wordpress, click "HTML" to have the source code version
- Paste at the correct place within your post (using your usual paste method, eg. `CTRL-V`).

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use `the_content` filter along with some sort of parser, such as [PHPDOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), to remove the unneccessary tags.

Pseudocode:

```
function parse_my_content($html) {
    $phpdom = new \DOMDocument;
    $phpdom->loadHTML($html);
    // do some parser magic ....
    $result = $phpdom->saveHTML();
    return $result;

}

add_filter('the_content', 'parse_my_content', 11, 1);

// if you do not want to save it to database, fires on each adding/editing the post
add_filter('wp_insert_post', function($post_arr) {
    $post_arr->content = parse_my_content($post_arr);
    return $post_arr;
});
```